# How Do I Pass Params To SP in EF6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am using a pattern that I got out of a tutorial text.  I am using EF6, Database First.  It is a Repository pattern.  I can't figure out how to pass parameters to to SPs.

There's a class called EFRepository with samples of returning complete tables or record by ID as follows:

```
public class EFRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    public EFRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        if (dbContext == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("dbContext");
        DbContext = dbContext;
        DbSet = DbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    protected DbContext DbContext { get; set; }
    protected DbSet<T> DbSet { get; set; }
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }

    public virtual T GetById(int id)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(id);
    }
```

The interface class looks like this:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    //To query using LINQ
    IQueryable<T> GetAll();
    //Return by ID
    T GetById(int id);
```

I tried adding this to EF Repository

```
   public virtual IQueryable<T> GetBySpParams(List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter> myParams)
    {
        return DbSet.Find(myParams);
    }
```

with this in the Interface:

```
    IQueryable<T> GetBySpParams(List<System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter> myParams);
```

But this does not work.  Assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So what exactly doesn't work? you are not showing how you are calling SP with EF. `DBSet.Find` methods accepts one or more objects and search for a single record by id(s). it does not call any SP.

Comment: From my api, I can call GetAll or GetByID and pass an int.  What I can't do (or don't know how to) is to call a Stored Proc and pass it the Params.  For example, I can make this call               var model = Uow.<A DB Table or View>GetAll().OrderBy(m => m.Address).Select(m => new ContractedPropertyListModel

Comment: If you're doing database first you should have a model, an .edmx file? You can update the model from the database to include the SP and call the SP just like a function `DbContext.SPName(p1,p2)`

Comment: The model has the SP.  It is the way that the pattern implements the repository and interface that is the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can call a stored procedure with parameters:

```
 /* Declare your parameters and their values */
 SqlParameter[] myParams = new SqlParameter[2];
 myParams[0] = new SqlParameter("startDate", startDate);
 myParams[1] = new SqlParameter("endDate", endDate);


 return dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<YourReturnDataType>("Exec YourStoreProcedureName @startDate, @endDate", myParams).ToList();
```

Comment: return DbContext.SqlQuery<LoadContactsInvolved_Result>("Exec YourStoreProcedureName @startDate, @endDate", myParams).ToList();    Error CS1061 'DbContext' does not contain a definition for 'SqlQuery' and no extension method 'SqlQuery' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry. I changed the answer to address that error. Basically, the Database property of DBContext has several methods that allows you to rub SQL commands. The better solution would be using one of the async methods.

Comment: And here is the link to the Database class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.database(v=vs.113).aspx